# CSS puzzle: How to add background-image and set height/width on empty span?

Tags: html, css

I've set `background-image` on a couple of `span` elements, but they aren't showing up, I think because my `height` and `width` settings are being ignored.

HTML source:

```
<div class="textwidget">
<a href="#" title="Start here"><span id="starthere" class="sidebar-poster"></span></a> 
<a href="#" title="Primary documents"><span id="#primarydocs" class="sidebar-poster"></span></a> 
<a href="#" title="Donate"><span id="donate" class="sidebar-poster"></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span.sidebar-poster {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 160px;
}
span#starthere { 
    background-image: url(/betatesting/wp-content/themes/dynamik/css/images/brunelwantsyou180.jpg);
    height: 285px;
} 
span#starthere:hover { 
    background-image: url(/betatesting/wp-content/themes/dynamik/css/images/brunelwantsyou_hover.jpg);
} 
span#primarydocs { 
    background-image: url(/betatesting/wp-content/themes/dynamik/css/images/brunelwantsyou180.jpg);
    height: 285px;
} 
span#primarydocs:hover { 
    background-image: url(/betatesting/wp-content/themes/dynamik/css/images/brunelwantsyou_hover.jpg);
} 
span#donate { 
    background-image: url(/betatesting/wp-content/themes/dynamik/css/images/donatebutton.jpg);
    height: 285px;
} 
span#donate:hover { 
    background-image: url(/betatesting/wp-content/themes/dynamik/css/images/donateposter_hover.jpg);
}
```

None of the background images are actually visible.

In Chrome Developer Tools, Under Computed Style, these two spans do appear to have a background image. If I copy and paste the URL of this image, I see the image. Yet nothing is actually rendering.

**[UPDATE - this part is solved, thanks]** In Chrome Developer Tools, under Matched Rules, only the `#starthere` and `#donate` spans are actually picking up the `background-image` attribute. The `#primarydocs` span is not. Why not?

Comment: So the span elements have height 0px and width 0px, maybe that's it. Why? Why don't they have the height that I have given to them in the #id and the width in the sidebar-poster class?

Comment: `span id="#primarydocs"` should probably be `span id="primarydocs"`.

Comment: YES. Thank you, don't know how I didn't spot that! Now just have the widths to figure out.

Comment: Wider question: how could I have spotted that without posting on SO? Is there an equivalent of Firebug for CSS errors? Firebug was giving the cryptic error "Unexpected token in attribute selector !", but I'm not even sure that was related to this error.

Comment: @AP257: firebug lists all the rules that matched the element, so if you don't see a rule you expected to be there, you've usually misspelled the class/id or missed a comma in the selector rule. (At least, that's what I do.)

Comment: OFf-topic: you should use a `ul` for the list of links to be semantically correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SPAN` is an inline element. Which will indeed ignore such things. Try setting the display mode in your CSS to something like: `display: block;`

Answer (score 4):

I think your `span`s need to have `display:inline-block`, an ordinary span will always have its 'natural' width and height.

Comment: Note that inline-block isn't supported by I think at least IE6, maybe not 7 either. Honestly, I just remember it isn't "well supported", I don't remember the extent of it.

Comment: My excuse is that IE6 is so aaaaaancient I just don't give a s, and all platforms that had IE7 also got IE8. Thankfully I work in a nerdy place and might get away with it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since a  is `display: inline;` automatically it cannot take `width` and `height` attributes from CSS.

If you want to use the `inline` characteristic but without inner content (ie: `<span>`content`</span>`) and instead have a background image, use `padding` instead.

ie:

`span {
padding: 10px;
}`

but input the number of pixels you would need to show the image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - you can't set `height` and `width` on `span` because it is an inline element. Switching to `div` solved it.

Phew.

If anyone knows how to debug CSS with better tools than guesswork, hope, Google searches and swearing, please let me know!

Comment: Use Chrome and it's built-in developer tools, they're great!  Or if you are a Firefox junkie, use the FireBug add-on.  Both of these are fabulous debugging tools.