# CSS: image link, change on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is a link. I want to show a different image when the user hovers over the link.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/me" title="Twitter link">
<div id="twitterbird" class="sidebar-poster"></div></a>

div.sidebar-poster {
margin-bottom: 10px;
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 160px;
}
#twitterbird {
background-image: url('twitterbird.png');
}
#twitterbird:hover {
background-image: url('twitterbird_hover.png');
}
```

But I'm having loads of problems: the div isn't picking up the CSS rules (the element just isn't showing the related CSS rules when I view it in Firebug).

Perhaps this is because (as I know) this is invalid HTML: you can't put an `<a>` around a `<div>`. However, if I switch to `<span>` then it seems I get bigger problems, because [you can't set a height and width on a span reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716284/css-puzzle-how-to-add-background-image-and-set-height-width-on-empty-span).

Help! How can I do this better?

Comment: Actually I think NOW putting `<a>` around a `<div>` is allowed.

Comment: Oh OK... In that case, any idea why the CSS isn't being picked up? I thought that if I used id on the element, and # in the CSS, it would always pick it up.

Comment: Block level links are fine if you're using the HTML5 doctype. http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: what doctype are you using? in [html5 `a` elements can contain block level elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/me" class="twitterbird" title="Twitter link"></a>
```

use a class for the link itself and forget the div

```
.twitterbird {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 160px;
 height:160px;
 display:block;
 background:transparent url('twitterbird.png') center top no-repeat;
}

.twitterbird:hover {
   background-image: url('twitterbird_hover.png');
}
```

Comment: As the image is downloaded on demand, the first time somebody visits the page, there will be a split second where no image exists after hovering. Just wanted to point this out as it may be undesirable for some.

Answer (score 41):

If you have just a few places where you wish to create this effect, you can use the following html code that requires no css.  Just insert it.

```
<a href="TARGET URL GOES HERE"><img src="URL OF FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" 
onmouseover="this.src='URL OF IMAGE ON HOVER GOES HERE'"
onmouseout="this.src='URL OF FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE AGAIN'" /></A>
```

Be sure to write the quote marks exactly as they are here, or it will not work.

Comment: I have tried this and it is assume. I understand that this is JavaScript...

Could you kindly let me know how this can be done with CSS.

If possible I need the actual code as an example.

Answer (score 11):

The problem with changing it via JavaScript or CSS is that if you have a slower connection, the image will take a second to change to the hovered version. This will cause an undesirable flash as one disappears while the other downloads.

What I've done before is have two images. Then hide and show each depending on the hover state. This will allow for a clean switch between the two images.

```
<a href="/settings">
    <img class="default" src="settings-default.svg"/>
    <img class="hover" src="settings-hover.svg"/>
    <span>Settings</span>
</a>

a img.hover {
    display: none;
}
a img.default {
    display: inherit;
}
a:hover img.hover {
    display: inherit;
}
a:hover img.default {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Nice easy solution.

Answer (score 6):

That could be done with `<a>` only:

```
#twitterbird {
 display: block; /* 'convert' <a> to <div> */
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 background-position: center top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px;
 background-image: url('twitterbird.png');
}
#twitterbird:hover {
 background-image: url('twitterbird_hover.png');
}
```

Comment: You mean with something like `<a href="" id="twitterbird"></a>`? Unfortunately, that renders with width and height of 0 (even with the CSS classes you suggest) in Chrome.

Comment: okay, if I try a test page with just your suggestion it displays... so why have I got a height and width of 0 on my 'real' page? I've tried setting `height: 160px ! important` but it doesn't help...

Comment: ...to explain: in Chrome Developer Tools, all the styles above show up under 'Matched Rules', but then in the 'Computed Style' section, the height and width are zero! For no apparent reason. Why?

Comment: I've created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717673/css-mystery-width-being-set-to-0px-without-any-css-rules

Answer (score 4):

It can be better if you set the a element in this way

```
display:block;
```

and then by [css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) set your over background

Edit: check this example out http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/dTwtk/

Comment: Thanks - I'll use sprites once I've worked out how to get the element itself displaying with a non-zero width.

Comment: If you set display:block, you should set a fixed width/height to the <a> element ;)

Comment: also, check this example out http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/dTwtk/ ..it will help you ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following, without needing CSS...

```
<a href="ENTER_DESTINATION_URL"><img src="URL_OF_FIRST_IMAGE_SOURCE" onmouseover="this.src='URL_OF_SECOND_IMAGE_SOURCE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL_OF_FIRST_IMAGE_SOURCE_AGAIN'" /></a>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jord8on/k1zsfqyk/

This solution was PERFECT for my needs! I found this solution [here](http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/05/create-rollover-image-effect-change.html).

**Disclaimer:** *Having a solution that is possible without CSS is important to me because I design content on the Jive-x cloud community platform which does not give us access to global CSS.*

Answer (score 0):

If you give generally give a `span` the property `display:block`, it'll  then behave like a `div`, i.e you can set width and height.

You can also skip the `div` or `span` and just set the `a` the  to `display: block` and apply the backgound style to it.

```
<a href="" class="myImage"><!----></a>


    <style>
      .myImage {display: block; width: 160px; height: 20px; margin:0 0 10px 0; background: url(image.png) center top no-repeat;}
.myImage:hover{background-image(image_hover.png);}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Change Image on Hover in CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .card {
        width: 130px;
        height: 195px;
        background: url("../images/pic.jpg") no-repeat;
        margin: 50px;
    }
    .card:hover {
        background: url("../images/anotherpic.jpg") no-repeat;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</body>
</html>
```