# Setting a width and height on an A tag

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Is it possible to set the width and height in pixels on an anchor tag? I'd like to have the anchor tag to have a background image while retaining the text inside the anchor.

```css
li {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: orange;
}

li a {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
```

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You need to make your anchor `display: block` or `display: inline-block;` and then it will accept the width and height values.

Comment: +1, this works but can you please tell me the reason why display: block or display: inline-block; is making width and height work in this case?

Comment: li is an inline tag and you cannot give width height properties to inline tags. Width height are not applicable on them it is as simple as that. When you give it display inline-block it starts to act as both inline and block and accepts block properties too.

Answer (score 67):

You can also use `display: inline-block`. The advantage of this is that it will set the height and width like a block element but also set it inline so that you can have another a tag sitting right next to it, permitting the parent space.

You can find out more about [display properties here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display)

Comment: I was looking for a solution to set the width of the anchor tag as its text content and not in a certain width and height, so setting it to "inline-block" did the trick exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

All these suggestions work unless you put the anchors inside an UL list.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>click me</a>>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then any cascade style sheet rules are overridden in the Chrome browser. The width becomes auto. Then you must use inline CSS rules directly on the anchor itself.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an exact duplicate (so far as I can find), but this is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717673/css-mystery-width-being-set-to-0px-without-any-css-rules/4717702#4717702).

`display:block` is what you need. but you should [read the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Below working for me

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: block` on the anchor element is a solid suggestion, but I can think of another scenario that doesn't require explicitly setting it.

Supposethe anchor is nested inside a div element with `display: flex` property. Then all the direct children of this div aka flex items become block elements and you can set height to the anchor.

If the background image's height is not capped, however, it will cause overflow. So apply `height: 100%` to the it.

Below is an example. Please note that the background image in the example is SVG, but SVG is inline by default, so you can replace it with an  element and get the same result.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.link {
  height: 48px;
}
.svg-logo {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<a class="link">
<svg class="svg-logo" viewBox="0 0 184 25" fill="#000"><path d="M13.8 2.9c0-2-1.9-2.5-3.4-2.5v.3c.9 0 1.6.3 1.6 1 0 .4-.3 1-1.2 1-.7 0-2.2-.4-3.3-.8C6.2 1.4 5 1 4 1 2 1 .6 2.5.6 4.2c0 1.5 1.1 2 1.5 2.2l.1-.2c-.2-.2-.5-.4-.5-1 0-.4.4-1.1 1.4-1.1.9 0 2.1.4 3.7.9 1.4.4 2.9.7 3.7.8v3.1L9 10.2v.1l1.5 1.3v4.3c-.8.5-1.7.6-2.5.6-1.5 0-2.8-.4-3.9-1.6l4.1-2V6l-5 2.2C3.6 6.9 4.7 6 5.8 5.4l-.1-.3c-3 .8-5.7 3.6-5.7 7 0 4 3.3 7 7 7 4 0 6.6-3.2 6.6-6.5h-.2c-.6 1.3-1.5 2.5-2.6 3.1v-4.1l1.6-1.3v-.1l-1.6-1.3V5.8c1.5 0 3-1 3-2.9zm-8.7 11l-1.2.6c-.7-.9-1.1-2.1-1.1-3.8 0-.7 0-1.5.2-2.1l2.1-.9v6.2zm10.6 2.3l-1.3 1 .2.2.6-.5 2.2 2 3-2-.1-.2-.8.5-1-1V9.4l.8-.6 1.7 1.4v6.1c0 3.8-.8 4.4-2.5 5v.3c2.8.1 5.4-.8 5.4-5.7V9.3l.9-.7-.2-.2-.8.6-2.5-2.1L18.5 9V.8h-.2l-3.5 2.4v.2c.4.2 1 .4 1 1.5l-.1 11.3zM34 15.1L31.5 17 29 15v-1.2l4.7-3.2v-.1l-2.4-3.6-5.2 2.8v6.6l-1 .8.2.2.9-.7 3.4 2.5 4.5-3.6-.1-.4zm-5-1.7V8.5l.2-.1 2.2 3.5-2.4 1.5zM53.1 2c0-.3-.1-.6-.2-.9h-.2c-.3.8-.7 1.2-1.7 1.2-.9 0-1.5-.5-1.9-.9l-2.9 3.3.2.2 1-.9c.6.5 1.1.9 2.5 1v8.3L44 3.2c-.5-.8-1.2-1.9-2.6-1.9-1.6 0-3 1.4-2.8 3.6h.3c.1-.6.4-1.3 1.1-1.3.5 0 1 .5 1.3 1v3.3c-1.8 0-3 .8-3 2.3 0 .8.4 2 1.6 2.3v-.2c-.2-.2-.3-.4-.3-.7 0-.5.4-.9 1.1-.9h.5v4.2c-2.1 0-3.8 1.2-3.8 3.2 0 1.9 1.6 2.8 3.4 2.7v-.2c-1.1-.1-1.6-.6-1.6-1.3 0-.9.6-1.3 1.4-1.3.8 0 1.5.5 2 1.1l2.9-3.2-.2-.2-.7.8c-1.1-1-1.7-1.3-3-1.5V5l8 14h.6V5c1.5-.1 2.9-1.3 2.9-3zm7.3 13.1L57.9 17l-2.5-2v-1.2l4.7-3.2v-.1l-2.4-3.6-5.2 2.8v6.6l-1 .8.2.2.9-.7 3.4 2.5 4.5-3.6-.1-.4zm-5-1.7V8.5l.2-.1 2.2 3.5-2.4 1.5zM76.7 8l-.7.5-1.9-1.6-2.2 2 .9.9v7.5l-2.4-1.5V9.6l.8-.5-2.3-2.2-2.2 2 .9.9V17l-.3.2-2.1-1.5v-6c0-1.4-.7-1.8-1.5-2.3-.7-.5-1.1-.8-1.1-1.5 0-.6.6-.9.9-1.1v-.2c-.8 0-2.9.8-2.9 2.7 0 1 .5 1.4 1 1.9s1 .9 1 1.8v5.8l-1.1.8.2.2 1-.8 2.3 2 2.5-1.7 2.8 1.7 5.3-3.1V9.2l1.3-1-.2-.2zm18.6-5.5l-1 .9-2.2-2-3.3 2.4V1.6h-.3l.1 16.2c-.3 0-1.2-.2-1.9-.4l-.2-13.5c0-1-.7-2.4-2.5-2.4s-3 1.4-3 2.8h.3c.1-.6.4-1.1 1-1.1s1.1.4 1.1 1.7v3.9c-1.8.1-2.9 1.1-2.9 2.4 0 .8.4 2 1.6 2V13c-.4-.2-.5-.5-.5-.7 0-.6.5-.8 1.3-.8h.4v6.2c-1.5.5-2.1 1.6-2.1 2.8 0 1.7 1.3 2.9 3.3 2.9 1.4 0 2.6-.2 3.8-.5 1-.2 2.3-.5 2.9-.5.8 0 1.1.4 1.1.9 0 .7-.3 1-.7 1.1v.2c1.6-.3 2.6-1.3 2.6-2.8s-1.5-2.4-3.1-2.4c-.8 0-2.5.3-3.7.5-1.4.3-2.8.5-3.2.5-.7 0-1.5-.3-1.5-1.3 0-.8.7-1.5 2.4-1.5.9 0 2 .1 3.1.4 1.2.3 2.3.6 3.3.6 1.5 0 2.8-.5 2.8-2.6V3.7l1.2-1-.2-.2zm-4.1 6.1c-.3.3-.7.6-1.2.6s-1-.3-1.2-.6V4.2l1-.7 1.4 1.3v3.8zm0 3c-.2-.2-.7-.5-1.2-.5s-1 .3-1.2.5V9c.2.2.7.5 1.2.5s1-.3 1.2-.5v2.6zm0 4.7c0 .8-.5 1.6-1.6 1.6h-.8V12c.2-.2.7-.5 1.2-.5s.9.3 1.2.5v4.3zm13.7-7.1l-3.2-2.3-4.9 2.8v6.5l-1 .8.1.2.8-.6 3.2 2.4 5-3V9.2zm-5.4 6.3V8.3l2.5 1.8v7.1l-2.5-1.7zm14.9-8.4h-.2c-.3.2-.6.4-.9.4-.4 0-.9-.2-1.1-.5h-.2l-1.7 1.9-1.7-1.9-3 2 .1.2.8-.5 1 1.1v6.3l-1.3 1 .2.2.6-.5 2.4 2 3.1-2.1-.1-.2-.9.5-1.2-1V9c.5.5 1.1 1 1.8 1 1.4.1 2.2-1.3 2.3-2.9zm12 9.6L123 19l-4.6-7 3.3-5.1h.2c.4.4 1 .8 1.7.8s1.2-.4 1.5-.8h.2c-.1 2-1.5 3.2-2.5 3.2s-1.5-.5-2.1-.8l-.3.5 5 7.4 1-.6v.1zm-11-.5l-1.3 1 .2.2.6-.5 2.2 2 3-2-.2-.2-.8.5-1-1V.8h-.1l-3.6 2.4v.2c.4.2 1 .3 1 1.5v11.3zM143 2.9c0-2-1.9-2.5-3.4-2.5v.3c.9 0 1.6.3 1.6 1 0 .4-.3 1-1.2 1-.7 0-2.2-.4-3.3-.8-1.3-.4-2.5-.8-3.5-.8-2 0-3.4 1.5-3.4 3.2 0 1.5 1.1 2 1.5 2.2l.1-.2c-.3-.2-.6-.4-.6-1 0-.4.4-1.1 1.4-1.1.9 0 2.1.4 3.7.9 1.4.4 2.9.7 3.7.8V9l-1.5 1.3v.1l1.5 1.3V16c-.8.5-1.7.6-2.5.6-1.5 0-2.8-.4-3.9-1.6l4.1-2V6l-5 2.2c.5-1.3 1.6-2.2 2.6-2.9l-.1-.2c-3 .8-5.7 3.5-5.7 6.9 0 4 3.3 7 7 7 4 0 6.6-3.2 6.6-6.5h-.2c-.6 1.3-1.5 2.5-2.6 3.1v-4.1l1.6-1.3v-.1L140 8.8v-3c1.5 0 3-1 3-2.9zm-8.7 11l-1.2.6c-.7-.9-1.1-2.1-1.1-3.8 0-.7.1-1.5.3-2.1l2.1-.9-.1 6.2zm12.2-12h-.1l-2 1.7v.1l1.7 1.9h.2l2-1.7v-.1l-1.8-1.9zm3 14.8l-.8.5-1-1V9.3l1-.7-.2-.2-.7.6-1.8-2.1-2.9 2 .2.3.7-.5.9 1.1v6.5l-1.3 1 .1.2.7-.5 2.2 2 3-2-.1-.3zm16.7-.1l-.7.5-1.1-1V9.3l1-.8-.2-.2-.8.7-2.3-2.1-3 2.1-2.3-2.1L154 9l-1.8-2.1-2.9 2 .1.3.7-.5 1 1.1v6.5l-.8.8 2.3 1.9 2.2-2-.9-.9V9.3l.9-.6 1.5 1.4v6l-.8.8 2.3 1.9 2.2-2-.9-.9V9.3l.8-.5 1.6 1.4v6l-.7.7 2.3 2.1 3.1-2.1v-.3zm8.7-1.5l-2.5 1.9-2.5-2v-1.2l4.7-3.2v-.1l-2.4-3.6-5.2 2.8v6.8l3.5 2.5 4.5-3.6-.1-.3zm-5-1.7V8.5l.2-.1 2.2 3.5-2.4 1.5zm14.1-.9l-1.9-1.5c1.3-1.1 1.8-2.6 1.8-3.6v-.6h-.2c-.2.5-.6 1-1.4 1-.8 0-1.3-.4-1.8-1L176 9.3v3.6l1.7 1.3c-1.7 1.5-2 2.5-2 3.3 0 1 .5 1.7 1.3 2l.1-.2c-.2-.2-.4-.3-.4-.8 0-.3.4-.8 1.2-.8 1 0 1.6.7 1.9 1l4.3-2.6v-3.6h-.1zm-1.1-3c-.7 1.2-2.2 2.4-3.1 3l-1.1-.9V8.1c.4 1 1.5 1.8 2.6 1.8.7 0 1.1-.1 1.6-.4zm-1.7 8c-.5-1.1-1.7-1.9-2.9-1.9-.3 0-1.1 0-1.9.5.5-.8 1.8-2.2 3.5-3.2l1.2 1 .1 3.6z"></path></svg>
</a>
</div>
```

So all in all, this is a roundabout way of setting `display: block` to anchor element, but I feel like pointing it out because the layout above is very common in header logos.