# Anchor (<a>) dimensions with only inline-block spans inside

Tags: layout, anchor, html, css

Could someone explain me what's going on with this small piece of HTML ?

http://jsbin.com/akome5

On most of current browsers (FF4, Chrome10, IE9, IE8, Opera 11), the layout of the  element looks like this :

[image]

Meh?! I don't understand why ?!
Why aren't the  height and width as big as the visible box (orange+red spaces) ?

Adding a "display:inline-block;" to the  element doesn't seems to really fix it.
How can I fix it ?

Thx!!

Comment: "Why aren't the height and width as big as the visible box" height and width of what?

Comment: The blue box highlights the element, while the OP is asking why the blue box doesn't span the *entire* height of the red-and-orange box.

Comment: Exactly :) Width & Height & Position of the blue box (firebug hover) are not those expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - [Setting a width and height on an A tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743254/setting-a-width-and-height-on-an-a-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following styles.

```
a.button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
a.button span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. But is overflow: auto; really necessary?
Moreover I need to add an element after the button(s) to stop the float (something like <br clear="all"/>), that can become somewhat complex to manage.

Comment: The { overflow: auto } just makes the container (a.button) wrap its floated contents (the spans).  Otherwise, it won't respect the spans' heights.  You can use { clear: left } on the next following element to end the float.  But I was just trying to ask your question in a simple manner, and have not looked ahead to other issues that might arise in a page that used this code.  Good luck :p

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose a different approach involving no spans

html:

```
<a class="button2" href="#">Text Text Text</a>
```

css:

```
/* Button 2 */
.button2 {
    background-color:red;
    border:solid 10px orange;
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 3px;
}
```

[image: old (top) new (bottom)]

old (top) new (bottom)

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/vr7gJ/

Comment: Thx but this is not what I asked in the first place! I'm trying to understand WHY dimensions are not those expected.
Moreover I need 3 element because in the real button I'm using background images & more styles.

Answer (score 0):

For information I manage to do it without float:left, here is the whole CSS :

```
a.button{
    display: inline-block; /* <- added */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button span{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /* <- added */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button .left, a.button .right{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 10px;
}

a.button .text{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

The **line-height** instruction was the key.

Comment: Nicely done.  I don't want to pee on your bonfire but bear in mind that IE 6 & 7 and Firefox 2 don't support { display: inline-block }.  On Firefox 2 you can use -moz-inline-block and there are various hacks around the web for IE 6 & 7.  I doubt you're supporting FF2 though, and IE 6 & 7 will soon be dead, if we're lucky.  Well done.