# HTML button only uses width and height of text in the button

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem. I am trying to change the width and height of a button but for some reason, it will not let me. The button automatically stays the same width and height as the contained text.

CSS

```
.flexcontainer {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

img[width="500"] {
border: 3px solid #5F5F5F;
border-radius:3px;
float: left;
}

#leftRetail {
display: block;
height:354px;
width: 1308px;
float:right;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 354px;
}

.button {
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
background: #ed2626;
border-radius: 2px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="flexcontainer">
            <div>
                <img src="anyImage.jpg" width="500" height="350"/>
            </div>
            <div id="leftRetail">
                <a href="Template.pdf" class= "button">Retail Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a width and height on an A tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743254/setting-a-width-and-height-on-an-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGED ANSWER after copying the original code into a snippet:

I just realized that the whole thing is inside a flex container, which makes all child elements flex items automatically. (BTW: The `float` parameters have no effect in this case)

So, one method to add width and height to your `.button` is to give it some padding, as shown below:

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img[width="500"] {
  border: 3px solid #5F5F5F;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#leftRetail {
  height: 354px;
  width: 1308px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 354px;
}

.button {
  background: #ed2626;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div>
    <img src="anyImage.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
  </div>
  <div id="leftRetail">
    <a href="Template.pdf" class="button">Retail Menu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I change it to a block element, the 'button' (i know it isn't actually a button) jumps up to the top left corner of my left retail div, which makes it sit to the top right of the image?

Comment: Apologies, the text doesn't dissapear it is just white so i could not see it. the text stays in the center of the div but the block moves to the top right corner

Comment: I have. that didnt work. I need the block and the text to both be centered as they were previously, but being able to change the width and height also

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your .button to use display: block or inline-block:

```
.button {
display: block;
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
background: #ed2626;
border-radius: 2px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: If I do that the button jumps up to beside the top right corner of the picture and my text disappears?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the width and height of `inline` elements, manually.

Add `display: block;` (or `inline-block`) to your `.button` block, and you can observe that the height and width changes are you define it.

Only [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements may have their width and height set specifically.

Your button should now look like:

```
.button {
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
background: #ed2626;
border-radius: 2px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: If I do that the button jumps up to beside the top right corner of the picture and my text disappears?

Answer (score 0):

Just make it *block-level element* by adding `display:bock` to its style. Then you can apply whatever style you want!