# How can I restrict the width of inline anchor element?

Tags: html, css

I followed the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2011199/325868) for a HTML approach for a tooltip. My current sample code looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      sup.footnote::after {
        content: attr(data-count);
      }
      sup.footnote:hover {
        cursor: help;
        position: relative;
      }
      sup.footnote cite {
        display: none;
      }
      sup.footnote:hover cite {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: -50%;
        width: 250px;
        background: #f0f0f0 no-repeat 100% 5%;
        border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Dies ist ein Beispiel für eine Fußnote in HTML
      <sup class="footnote" data-count="1">
        <cite>
          <span> [Sample span]</span>&nbsp;with some explanation:
          <a lang="en" href="http://test.gv.at/test.pdf">
            http://test.gv.at/test/test/abde4/iabcde/009909asdf/vandsfk23/verylong/gghhy.pdf
          </a>
        </cite>
      </sup>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I don't know how to restrict the `anchor` element with length. While FF breaks the `anchor` nicely Chrome has troubles to do so.

[image]

I found solutions like [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743269/325868) `display` for anchor but Chrome doesn't perform any kind of change. Perhaps I did it on the wrong elements or with the wrong style.

==> Is there a way to limit the length of the `anchor` to e.g. `250px`?

Comment: Either allow word breaking (`word-break` / `overflow-wrap`), or make the link inline-block, give it a (max) width, and hide any overflow.

Comment: Setting the width won't work. `word-break` and/or `overflow-wrap` work both. Which to prefer or which choose? If you make an answer ==> I'll accept it. Thx. AND: Why does work in FF and Chrome not? (As another topic)

Comment: What does "limit the length" mean? Truncate? Wrap? Both have been well covered on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your text (link) has no spaces. It's like a huge word which needs to be handled in CSS. It's also a CSS meme btw.

[image: css-is-awesome]

Here are some solutions:

## Solution 1

Just use [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) with value `break-word` or `break-all`.

```css
sup.footnote cite a {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```css
sup.footnote::after {
  content: attr(data-count);
}
sup.footnote:hover {
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
}
sup.footnote cite {
  display: none;
}
sup.footnote:hover cite {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -50%;
  width: 250px;
  background: #f0f0f0 no-repeat 100% 5%;
  border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
}
sup.footnote cite a {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Dies ist ein Beispiel für eine Fußnote in HTML
  <sup class="footnote" data-count="1">
    <cite>
      <span> [Sample span]</span>&nbsp;with some explanation:
      <a lang="en" href="http://test.gv.at/test.pdf">
        http://test.gv.at/test/test/abde4/iabcde/009909asdf/vandsfk23/verylong/gghhy.pdf
      </a>
    </cite>
  </sup>
</p>
```

[image: result]

---

## Solution 2

Or prevent word break use [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) if you want to keep the tooltip height. Like this:

```css
sup.footnote::after {
  content: attr(data-count);
}
sup.footnote:hover {
  cursor: help;
  position: relative;
}
sup.footnote cite {
  display: none;
}
sup.footnote:hover cite {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -50%;
  width: 250px;
  background: #f0f0f0 no-repeat 100% 5%;
  border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
sup.footnote cite a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Dies ist ein Beispiel für eine Fußnote in HTML
  <sup class="footnote" data-count="1">
    <cite>
      <span> [Sample span]</span>&nbsp;with some explanation:
      <a lang="en" href="http://test.gv.at/test.pdf">
        http://test.gv.at/test/test/abde4/iabcde/009909asdf/vandsfk23/verylong/gghhy.pdf
      </a>
    </cite>
  </sup>
</p>
```

[image: result2]

Comment: Thx - works great - especially the second approach :-)

Comment: Both solutions work independent from the browser :-)

Comment: I have a follow up question to your solution in https://stackoverflow.com/q/72742933/325868 Perhaps you have an idea.