# Logo isn't clickable after changing position absolute

Tags: css

```
<div id="header-logo-image">
    <a href="http://example.com/" rel="home">
        <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/head-logo.png />
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
#header-logo-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
#header-logo-image img {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
```

The link to my homepage seems to have vanished after moving my logo.      When I hover over `<a>` section it says 0 x 0 for the sizes.

Does making a img smaller or even making it absolute position result in resetting the href link.

As the image is dynamic size, 60% I cannot specify a size in the a section

Comment: can you provide a fiddle please? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: [That's why it's 0x0.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717673/css-mystery-width-being-set-to-0px-without-any-css-rules)

Answer (score 1):

Change your line of code:

```
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/head-logo.png" /></a></div>
```