# jQuery Hover image change animation

Tags: jquery

I have an IMG tag with a grayscale image. I hooked up a Hover() event in order to change the "src" to a color image on hover, and back to grayscale on mouse-out.

This works just fine, however the change is abrupt. I'd like to add a slight fadeIn() to the effect so that the color appears to fadein and fadeout. I wrote the following which I thought would work, but doesn't. (The image changes, but there is no fade or delay to the effect). What am I doing wrong?

```
            $("#showForm").hover(
              function () {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    $(this).attr("src", 'images/AddButtonSmall.gif');
                });
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    $(this).attr("src", 'images/AddButtonSmallGray.gif');
                });
              }
            );
```

Comment: You can't fade in a `.src` change.  To fadeIn a new image while the old one fades out, you would mostly like need to use two overlapping images and fade on in and the other out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a couple solutions. Your code doesn't work because you are setting the source which changes the image immediately. It's probably easier just to load both images, overlay them with CSS and then fade the color one in out when the parent container is moused over. Alternatively you could cross fade them

css

```
.fader { display: inline-block; }
.fader img:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}​
```

html

```
<div class="fader">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/000fff" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/fff000" />
</div>​
```

fade in on mouseover

http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/3/

```
$('.fader').hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img:last").fadeToggle();
});​
```

cross fade

http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/2/

```
$('.fader').hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").fadeToggle();
});​
```

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thanks, didn't know about `fadeToggle`!

Comment: Hi @mrtsherman how would you write your CSS in SASS? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905061/last-child-and-last-of-type-not-working-in-sass

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).fadeIn('slow',
```

is actually trying to fade in the this element, slowly, and 'this' refers to

```
$("#showForm")
```

Instead if you want you could put the color image directly over the current grayscale image, and mark the color image hidden, then have it slowly fade in.  Assuming they are positioned on top of one another you could do:

```
$("#showForm").hover(
    function () {
       $("#colorImageID").fadeIn();
    }, 
    function () {
       $("#colorImageID").fadeOut();
    });
  }
```

);

assuming the html is something like (where sameAbsolutePosition is css to put them in the same exact spot, so maybe something like position:absolute; left:20; top:20px;):

```
<img src='images/AddButtonSmallGray.gif' class="sameAbsolutePosition">
<img src='images/AddButtonSmall.gif' style="display:none;" class="sameAbsolutePosition">
```

To reiterate, you'll be fading a new image on top of another image.  You could also fade the grayscale image out simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you fading out ?
Fade in does `display:block` with opacity changing from 0 to 100.
Fade out does `display:none` with opacity changing from 100 to 0.

Once, you fadeIn, image is `display:block` and opacity is 100. So, you dont see an animation.
So, either do a display:none or fadeOut before fadeIn again.

Given is example with explains things. You should change it according to your requirements.

```
$("#showForm").hover(
              function () {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    $(this).attr("src", 'images/AddButtonSmall.gif');
                });
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    $(this).attr("src", 'images/AddButtonSmallGray.gif');
                });
              }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Much better solution:

Forget about javascript to do this job. Use CSS's [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) instead. If you insist on having fadeIn, fadeOut, use transitions.

**UPDATE**: Responding to the comments below, I can't write some code since there is no way I can anticipate dimensions and positions in Todd's sprite. I also want to clarify that my suggestion is to use sprites and then transitions to enhance "functionality" and not only transitions because I assume he needs this to work in IE8 and IE9.

Comment: A site that talks about sprites and not at all about how to do image transitions isn't very helpful. This doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: Agree that the sprites comment isn't really related; but you COULD do this with a CSS3 transition; I'd just like to see the code.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I'm not really familiar with using sprites and I'd like to read up on it, so this was a good "prod" to do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 $("#showForm").hover(
          function () {
              $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
                 $(this).attr("src", 'images/AddButtonSmall.gif');
                 $("#img_src").html("images/AddButtonSmall.gif"); 
              });
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
          }, 
          function () {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
                 $(this).attr("src", 'images/AddButtonSmallGray.gif');
                 $("#img_src").html("images/AddButtonSmallGray.gif"); 
              });
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
          }
        );​
```

Here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/kmEF3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this cross fade with css3 using transition too.
Not available for all browsers but still...
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

In similar way to [CSS: image link, change on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717117/css-image-link-change-on-hover)

For example:

```
#showForm
{
    background: transparent url('images/AddButtonSmallGray.gif') center top no-repeat;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#showForm:hover {
    background-image: url('images/AddButtonSmall.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
         $(".image_hover").mouseover(function(){
        var old_src=$(this).attr("src");
        var new_src=$(this).attr("data-alt-src");
        $(this).attr('src', new_src);
        $(this).attr('data-alt-src', old_src);
      });
     $(".image_hover").mouseout(function(){
        var old_src=$(this).attr("src");
        var new_src=$(this).attr("data-alt-src");
        $(this).attr('src', new_src);
        $(this).attr('data-alt-src', old_src);
      });
```