# jQuery Hover Effect: Image gets smaller

Tags: jquery, hover

I want to switch between two image when hovering over it. Both images have the same dimensions and are congruent.

**The problem is when the image changes, it kind of "jumps" and gets smaller than the default image, although the HTML and CSS don't change and the images are the same dimensions. How comes?**

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<img src="image.png" class="image" />
```

The **jQuery script**:

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".image").hover(
            function() {$(this).attr("src","image-hover.png");}, 
            function() {$(this).attr("src","image.png");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can someone give some advice or hint why this is? **I am not looking for a CSS alternative, I want to make it work with jQuery!**

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: May be some script has already made your original (pre-hover) image bigger? Hard to tell without looking at your complete code. May be a jsfiddle?

Comment: without demo that replicates problem is anyone's guess what is happening

Comment: the problem is, i use a sass framework and it could be anything of the many files compiled to the css ...

i thought it might a popular problem with jQuery. I didn't know how to search for it, since "jumping images" didn't result in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a decent solution, even though I haven't solved the original problem.** But time is short, isn't it?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/3/

```
$('.fader').hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img:last").fadeToggle();
});​
```

found on:
[jQuery Hover image change animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039174/jquery-hover-image-change-animation)

Comment: also very smooth transitions.