# Change image once we hover on image is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

once we hover on image, i want to display another image.

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>',
           'google', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" 
     title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>"><img src ="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/G+.png') ?>"/></a>
</div>
```

i tried as below :

I added `class="a1"`, but it did't worked for me.

```html
<a class="a1"  href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>',
                     'google', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" 
   title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>"><img src ="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/G+.png') ?>"/></a>
```

**css**

```
.a1:hover {
   background-image: url('images/G+1.png');
}
```

Comment: Duplicate, you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717117/css-image-link-change-on-hover  :)

Comment: Set classes or IDs to your DIV and use `:hover` to change the images...

Comment: @AaronLavers please check updated questionand remove "duplicate"

Comment: @masmrdrr pls check updated question

Comment: You can use your css only if the first image is also in `background-image` but not an `img` tag as you do - as you can see in the attached question by @AaronLavers

Comment: You cant do this with  just css, since the first image is an img not a css image background. try javascript

Comment: @MoshFeu please update the code and post an answer.

Comment: `update the code` what do you mean? the code of who?

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe this is a duplicate however I have expanded the link into an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions for your query. (Change image on mouse hover)

**HTML + JavaScript Demo**

```html
<div class="image_hover">
  <a href="#" rel="nofollow">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h1hLX4Vb.jpg" height="160" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/h1hLX4Vb.jpg'" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/dmnwaafb.jpg'" width="160">
  </a>
</div>
```

**HTML + CSS Demo**

```css
.image_hover {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.image_hover img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
.image_hover img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_hover">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h1hLX4Vb.jpg" width="160" height="160"/>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dmnwaafb.jpg" width="160" height="160"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, give your link  tag some style, to set it's background.

```
a.a1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px; (width and height are whatever you need them to be)
  background: url('images/G+.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Now this is a very light example here, but what it is doing is setting your link as a block-level element, giving the right dimensions of the image background, and then setting the whole elements background as the image.

Then, for the rollover effect, you use:

```
a.a1:hover {
  background: url('images/G+1.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Now I like to put my no-repeat and positioning attributes in the `background` attribute, you can separate these into `background-size` etc if you really want.

I am aware in your implementation you have an `img` in there setting the picture, but for what you want to achieve I'd suggest using a css alternative.

SO link on the subject (as per comment):
[CSS: image link, change on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717117/css-image-link-change-on-hover)

Comment: i tried as you  said as here : `<a class="a1" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/G+.png') ?>');" href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'google', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>">
       </a>` now image is not visible. may be i am doing something wrong, please check code.

Comment: thnaks for support

Answer (score 2):

Additional the answer in @AaronLavers's comment (use `background-image` and replace it on `:hover`), you can use `:before` - pseudo class and `content` property.

**The plus**

It's generic solution. You have not to set the width and the height of the link - like in `background-image` way.

**The minus**

You can't change the image's size like using `background-size` etc. but if your image is the exact size you want, the problem solved.

```css
a:before {
  content:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/upUcm.jpg); 
}

a:hover:before {
  content:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn2Ag.jpg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Really good suggestion using pseudo elements to contain the image

Comment: i tried your css code, but than image is not visible. i may be  doing something wrong. can you please update the answer with complete code.

Comment: Which browser are using? If you create working snippet I will fix it for you.

Comment: thnaks for support

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because the img tag and background-image are 2 different things. If you want this to work, you could try putting the background image on the a to begin with and then changing it on hover. It needs important because of specificity rules. The other option would involve putting php in your css file, but that is probably not worth the effort to set up.

```
CSS
.a1:hover {
background-image: url('images/G+1.png') !important;
}

HTML
<a class="a1" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/G+.png') ?>');"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried like this , but didt worked for me : `<div>
    <a  style="background-image: url('<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/G+.png') ?>');" class="a1" 
 href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'google', 
 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>">
       </a>
                        </div>`

Comment: thnaks for support