# HTML Hover icon

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a very basic website only with HTML and CSS.
In the design, I added some icons, which are images. These images I've added them in my HTML.  I want to create a hover effect with another image. Any thoughts?

[image: Click here to view what the site looks life.]

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
.icon-group {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 15px;

}

.view-icon,
.edit-icon,
.delete-icon {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card one">
   <img class="avatar" src="images/avatar-01.jpg" alt="Foto Felipe Kaiser">
   <p class="name">Felipe Kaiser</p>
   <p class="position">Periodista</p>
   <hr>
   <div class="icon-group">
    <div class="view-icon">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/view-icon.png" alt="Icono ver">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="edit-icon">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/edit-icon.png" alt="Icono editar">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="delete-icon">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/delete-icon.png" alt="Icono delete">
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Look up css hover selector to find out how to do that. This codepen here has a whole bunch of live examples you can study, understand, then tweak it into your own project --> https://codepen.io/IanLunn/pen/hysxc

Comment: Please do your research. There are many many tutorials online that can help you here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: image link, change on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717117/css-image-link-change-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

To add a different behaviour of css while hovering any item, you have to define this behaviour and add `:hover` to the container id/class. In your exemple, it may be :

```
.icon-group {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon-group:hover {
background-color: grey;
}
```

for exemple